# Creating an online test with access database in C#

Tags: c#, database, generic-list

I need to create an online test with 10 questions. I have 30 questions stored in a database and every time the test is started, 10 questions have to be randomly picked. I managed to display the questions on a label, but I am showing all of them. What code do I need so only 10 questions will be displayed? Also there, since are multiple choice answers, I need to assign every answer option to a radio button. Answers are also stored in the database. What I've done so far (I've posted the relevant code only):

Code in the DBConnection class:

```
public static List<Questions> LoadQuestions()
{
    List<Questions> quest = new List<Questions>();
    OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
    string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Questions";
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Questions q = new Questions(Int32.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString()),                
                                        reader["QuestionBody"].ToString(),
                                        reader["CorrectAnswer"].ToString());
            quest.Add(q);
        }

        return quest;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler" + ex);
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}

public static List<Answers> LoadAnswers()
{
    List<Answers> answers = new List<Answers>();
    OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();

    string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Answers";
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Answers a = new Answers(Int32.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString()),
                                    reader["AnswerA"].ToString(),
                                    reader["AnswerB"].ToString(),
                                    reader["AnswerC"].ToString(),
                                    (Int32.Parse(reader["QuestionId"].ToString())));
            answers.Add(a);
        }

        return answers;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler" + ex);
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Code in the `Test.aspx`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Questions> QList = DatabaseConnecter.LoadQuestions();
    Random rndNumber = new Random();
    int randomQuest = rndNumber.Next(30);
    lblQuest.Text = QList[randomQuest].QuestionBody;

    List<Answers> AList = DatabaseConnecter.LoadAnswers();
    int a = 30;
    rbAnswer1.Text = AList[a].AnswerA;
}
```

I got the following error on the list line

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

The label (`lbwQuest`) displays questions just fine. The problem is with the answers and radio buttons (`rbAnswer1`, `rbAnswer2`, `rbAnswer3`). Also, in the database I have two tables - Questions with columns - ID, QuestionBody, CorrectAnswer, and Answers with columns - ID, QuestionID, AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC.

Comment: "I got the following error on the list line"   What do you mean by the "list" line?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific. I meant the last line. This is it:                                        rbAnswer1.Text = AList[a].AnswerA

Comment: The list `AList` might not have been instantiated. What exactly is supposed to be returned by `DatabaseConnecter.LoadAnswers();`. Ensure that it's returning correctly what you expect.

Comment: I need DatabaseConnector.LoadAnswers(); to return the answers from the database, more specific, It has to assign column - AnswerA to rbAnswer1, AnswerB to rbAnswe2 and AnswerC to rbAnswer3.There is also QuestionId column in the same table, so the answers should come up in the same order as the questions. But I am not sure how to do this right. I used breaking points and I could see that AList has a value of null, but all the properties seem fine, so I guess I haven't instantiated AList correctly.

Answer (score 1):

That error means You are trying to access properties / trying to call methods of a null object.

In your LoadQuestions function, if there is an exception caught, you are returning null.
Without checking if it is null or not, you are trying to access that with QList[randomQuest].QuestionBody. I would add a null checking to make the code more robust.

```
    List<Questions> QList = DatabaseConnecter.LoadQuestions();
    Random rndNumber = new Random();
    int randomQuest = rndNumber.Next(30);
    if((QList!=null) && (QList .Count>0))
    {
       lblQuest.Text = QList[randomQuest].QuestionBody;
    }
    else
    {
       lblQuest.Text = "Questions are not loaded!";
    }


    List<Answers> AList = DatabaseConnecter.LoadAnswers();
    int a = 30;
    if((AList!==null) && (AList.Count>0))
    {
       rbAnswer1.Text = AList[a].AnswerA;
    }
    else
    {
       rbAnswer1.Text = "Answers are not loaded!";
    }
```

Put breakpoints in your LoadQuestions and LoadAnswers methods and see where it is breaking. You can see whether an object is null or not using watch window also